# Django: How to pass a list of PKIDs to next view through AJAX, then redirect

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, django-views, django-urls

Premise:

- The user is presented a table with a list of objects with checkboxes
  next to them.
- The user is able to check as many checkboxes as they want.
- The user then clicks a button that will redirect them to another
  page, that does stuff with only those objects that were selected.

So I need to pass an array of object IDs I capture through jQuery to my next view (from here on GraphView) through a POST request embedded in a button, to show a list of only those objects on the next redirected page. How do I handle that in my URLs and in my view?

My jQuery:

```
// This is the event listener for the button click that would redirect you to the next page
$("#graphRuns").click(function() {
    var array = [];

    // IDs come from checkboxes. You select which objects you want
    // in your next page, then click a button. Here I determine
    // which IDs to add to the array through a data-attribute
    // on my HTML object templates
    choiceContainer.find("input:checked").each(function() {
        var run_id = $(this).data("run_id");
        array.push(run_id);
    });

    // I checked and the list of IDs is correct.
    console.log(array)

    // So I do a post request to the next view I want, passing the array of IDs.
    $.post("{% url 'expert_import:chart_runs' %}", {
        csrfmiddlewaretoken: "{{csrf_token}}",
        array: array
    }, function(data) {
        // location.reload();
        // Redirect here???
    }).done();
});
```

My URLs is where I think I'm doing this wrong:

```
url(r'^runs/chart$', ChartRunsView.as_view(), name='chart_runs'),
```

And in my views.py for GraphView (the one where you go when you click the button):

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    # I can confirm the array gets to the view here.
    print(request.POST)

    # This is a strange bit though, the array coming in request.POST
    # is named "array[]", when I never added the brackets
    # in my JS var declaration, and the next line is only
    # grabbing the last element in the incoming array
    ids_array = (request.POST.get("array[]"))

    runs = []
    for run_id in ids_array:
        runs.append(Run.objects.filter(pk=run_id))

return render(request, self.template_name, {'runs': runs})
```

I have several questions about this. Keep in mind please I'm new at Django and programming in general!

1. Should I be directing the AJAX post to the URL that shows the list
   of objects I select from (**TableView**), or should I direct the post to the URL of
   the view where I am going to use the array of IDs (**GraphView**)?
2. Should I be doing the redirect on the AJAX post "done" portion of
   the function? Or in the views (either **TableView** or (GraphView**) after I get the list of objects from my
   DB?
3. Should I have some RegEx in my URL for the page I want to redirect
   to, to handle the list of object IDs? (Caveat, I don't know how many
   objects the user will select)

I feel like I should be sending the POST request to the **TableView**, along with some kind of flag. Then on **TableView**'s "def post:" determine through Python if that flag is present and handle the redirect to the next page/view (**GraphView**), where I need the list of selected objects.

Not sure what the correct approach is here.

Also, I might be overcomplicating things with the AJAX, but I'm not sure how to set up a URL to take a list from a href or how to code that into a button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

POST methods usually [save data to the database](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods). You should be using a GET method to render the template. Also the AJAX here is useless.

What you should do is simply generate a link in javascript and redirect to the GraphView. The link would contain a list of the IDs selected. Here is a simple function that generates the link:

```
function generateLink(ids_list){
    var url = '"{% url 'app_name:graph_view' %}"';
    url += "?id=" + ids_list.join('&id=')
    return url;
}
```

In your GraphView you can read the IDs using `request.GET.getlist('id')`

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer. This solved my problem exactly as I needed it. I got caught up in thinking the request was a POST, I didn't think it'd be as simple as a get from the ChartView.

You're a lifesaver and I wish you much success in the future! ;)